# Compiling Error

Tags: ide, avr-gcc, compiler

I am trying  to compile this code on arduino IDE...It showing error
code is

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 6;
int led = 12;//1FE50AF
int led1 = 10;//1FED827 
int led2 = 9; //1FEF807
int led3 = 8;//1FE3087
int led4 = 7;//1FEB04F
boolean previousState=LOW;
boolean previousState1=LOW;
boolean previousState2=LOW;
boolean previousState3=LOW;
boolean previousState4=LOW;
boolean state;
boolean state1;
boolean state2;
boolean state3;
boolean state4;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();// Start the receiver 
}
void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) 
  {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    switch(results.value)
    {
       case 0x1FE50AF:
       if (previousState == LOW)
       {state=HIGH;
        digitalWrite(led,state);
       previousState=state;}
       else
       {state=LOW;
       digitalWrite(led,state);
       previousState=state;}
       break;
        case 0x1FED827:
       if (previousState1 == LOW)
       {state=HIGH;
        digitalWrite(led1,state1);
       previousState1=state1;}
       else
       {state1=LOW;
       digitalWrite(led1,state1);
       previousState1=state1;}
       break;
       case 0x1FEF807:
       if (previousState2 == LOW)
       {state2=HIGH;
       digitalWrite(led2,state2);
       previousState2=state2;}
       else
       {state2=LOW;
       digitalWrite(led2,state2);
       previousState2=state2;}
       break;
        case 0x1FE30CF:
       if (previousState3 == LOW)
       {state3=HIGH;
        digitalWrite(led3,state3);
       previousState3=state3;}
       else
       {state3=LOW;
       digitalWrite(led3,state3);
       previousState3=state3;}
       break;
        case 0x1FEB04F:
       if (previousState4 == LOW)
       {state4=HIGH;
        digitalWrite(led4,state4);
       previousState4=state4;}
       else
       {state4=LOW;
       digitalWrite(led4,state4);
       previousState4=state4;}
       break;
    }   
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

[image]

**Error massage which I Getting during compiling**

> Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows XP), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> Using library IRremote in folder: C:\Documents and Settings\Santanu
>   Mandal\My Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote (legacy)
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard -IC:\Documents
>   and Settings\Santanu Mandal\My Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IRrecvDemowithled.cpp
>   -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IRrecvDemowithled.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard -IC:\Documents
>   and Settings\Santanu Mandal\My Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote
>   -IC:\Documents and Settings\Santanu Mandal\My Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\utility C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Santanu Mandal\My
>   Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IRremote\IRremote.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -x
>   assembler-with-cpp -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605
>   -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.S -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_pulse.S.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\hooks.c -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\hooks.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WInterrupts.c -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\WInterrupts.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring.c
>   -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_analog.c -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_analog.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_digital.c -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_digital.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.c -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_pulse.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_shift.c -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_shift.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\abi.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\abi.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\CDC.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\CDC.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial0.cpp
>   -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial1.cpp
>   -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial2.cpp
>   -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial3.cpp
>   -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HID.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HID.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\IPAddress.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IPAddress.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\main.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\main.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\new.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\new.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Print.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\Print.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Stream.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\Stream.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Tone.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\Tone.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\USBCore.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\USBCore.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WMath.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\WMath.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os
>   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program
>   Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WString.cpp -o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\WString.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_pulse.S.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\hooks.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\WInterrupts.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_analog.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_digital.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_pulse.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\wiring_shift.c.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\abi.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\CDC.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\HID.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IPAddress.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\main.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\new.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\Print.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\Stream.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\Tone.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\USBCore.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\WMath.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-ar rcs
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\WString.cpp.o
>
> C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc -Os
>   -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/IRrecvDemowithled.cpp.elf
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IRrecvDemowithled.cpp.o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp\IRremote\IRremote.cpp.o
>   C:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp/core.a
>   -LC:\DOCUME~1\SANTAN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\build8586850450850335044.tmp -lm
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status Error compiling.

Comment: Windows XP...... Sorry but we are in 2016 (almost 2017) and Windows XP is like not even supported anymore (since a LONG LONG time). Could that be your problem??

Comment: I have been faced with this GCC LD issue on Windows a million times. I finally decided to build all my Arduino stuff on Linux without any problem. This LD issue has loads of reported errors, discussions on Internet, with various weird workarounds that sometimes work once but fail the next time...

Comment: Sir, I have used  IDE 1.6.12 to compile this code but it also give error    Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows XP), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status

Using library IRremote in folder: C:\Documents and Settings\Santanu Mandal\My Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote (legacy)
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

Answer (score 1):

You have been bitten by a bug in the compiler toolchain. [The bug has already been reported](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2989). Suggested workarounds:

- add a few unused global variables
- add some unused functions.